# How do I scroll the screen with the RecyclerView inside with RecyclerView load items step by step?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I have gallery page in my project. There are different view types in this page like RecyclerView - TextView - ImageView. If I set height "wrap_content" of RecyclerView, my RecyclerView loads all items. That's freeze to my view, because of some galleries has too many items. I want to load items step by step. But If I set height "match_constraint" of RecyclerView, my gallery page has 2 scroll (One of them is ScrollView, one of them is RecyclerView). So all view couldn't scroll with together. How do I scroll the screen with the RecyclerView inside with RecyclerView load items step by step?

Actually my **XML** is too long so I didn't add some views in following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/detail_fragment_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:focusable="true"
        tools:context=".DetailActivity">



 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/detail_fragment_constraint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:scrollbars="none">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/feed_detail_category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent” />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/feed_detail_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/feed_detail_category"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/feed_detail_category" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/feed_detail_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/feed_detail_category" />
          <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/comment_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/feed_detail_title” />         


 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: have you used pagination in that to load step by step? for two scroll problem you can disable scroll of recycler view via yourRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); before setting it a adapter.

Comment: If i use "yourRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);", I should set height "wrap_content" of my RecyclerView because of my RecyclerView can not scrolling, and my RecyclerView loads all items in this case.

Comment: I used to pagination at different views in this project, but in this case i can not use pagination, because of when loads so many items in pagination, this causes it to freeze too.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pagination library from Android Jetpack.
Check from official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/data).

You can also find a good tutorial [Here](https://proandroiddev.com/8-steps-to-implement-paging-library-in-android-d02500f7fffe)